# How can I compile apache PIG in IntelliJ?

Tags: ant, hadoop, intellij-idea, apache-pig

I'm trying to get apache pig running locally from source in IntelliJ. I'd like to step through the unit tests.

I've done the following steps:

```
git clone https://github.com/apache/pig.git
cd pig;
git checkout release-0.9.1
ant
```

Does anyone have instructions after that to get it imported into IntelliJ? It compiles fine from the cmd line with ant.

When I do FILE -> IMPORT PROJECT and then build I get complication errors complaining of duplicate classes. All I'm trying to do is BUILD -> MAKE PROJECT in intellij :/

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

found the answer:

git clone https://github.com/apache/pig.git

cd pig;

git checkout release-0.9.1

ant

ant eclipse-files

Open IntelliJ then do

FILE -> IMPORT

as type "ECLIPSE" project and away you go!